# drop columns dataframe which have 0 in any row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
   a  b  c 

   1. 0. 6
   2. 4. 7
   0. 8. 8
```

And I want to drop all columns which have 0 in any row, in this case I only want to keep column c

I have tried with `df.loc[:, (df != 0)]` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for test all values are not `0`:

```
df = df.loc[:, (df != 0).all()]
print (df)
   c
0  6
1  7
2  8
```